# Extract 'Locality' details from Reverse geo-coded address.

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am working with Location Manager to implement the same in my app, I want to show up the coffee shops around the physical location of a person. Based on what the phone shows, I am able to retrieve the latitude and longitude reverse geo-code them and get the location in a array-list. Now I am interested in the 'Locality' field in the result set. Any suggestion how do I get that? Below is my code.

```
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                     latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                     longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                     Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
                     try {
                        List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+myList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Iterator<Address> it = myList.iterator();

                            while (it.hasNext()) {

                                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                                tv.setText("Data is"+it.next());


                            }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with Address.getLocality !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! Here it goes:

```
   if (myList != null && myList.size() > 0) {
    Address address = myList.get(0);
    String result = address.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```